# Adding Custom Metafields For Products in Shopify using PHPISH API

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, shopify

I am developing an app in Shopify and I am using PHPISH SDK of Shopify. I have to insert some custom meta fields for products.

```
$(document).on('click', '.activate-btn', function(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://real-gun-rights.myshopify.com/admin/products/1364427588/metafields.json',
    data:{ "metafields": [{"namespace": "inventory", "key": "warehouse", "value": 25, "value_type":"integer" }]},
    crossDomain: true, 
    jsonp: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);

    }
});
});
```

Comment: marvellous you are sending data directly to a json file, you just broke the internet

Comment: first post the data to a php/asp/jsp page in that page open the file and append the data